# retrieve all paragraphs using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just a beginner at Javascript :)

I want to be able to receive all paragraphs in a text block (meaning all parts separated from each other with `<br/ >` tag), so I can apply different alignment settings on each such paragraph, depending on the language (ltr vs. rtl).

For example, if I have the following text:

```
Hello<br/>שלום
```

I would want "Hello" to be aligned to the left, and "שלום" to be aligned to the right.
Is it possible to use `document.evaluate` somehow?

Comment: You could probably use something like `document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML` and then do a split on `"<br/>"` for the grabbing paragraphs part.

Comment: if those two phrases are just bare text in your document, you'll have to wrap them in `<span>` or some other container, and then apply the alignment styles to that new container.

Comment: Personally I consider a paragraph to be separated by a blank line (so 2 `eol`'s after each other). If at all possible you could also wrap each paragraph in a `<p>` (paragraph) tag and then use `knownElement.getElementsByTagName('p')` to fetch them (and align them).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DOM subtree, you can just walk it depth-first looking for text nodes and BR elements.

```
var subtree = document.createElement('DIV');
subtree.innerHTML = 'Hello<br/>שלום';

var paragraphs = [""];
function walkSplittingOnBR(node) {
  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case 1:
      if (node.nodeName === 'BR') { paragraphs.push(''); }
      break;
    case 3:
      paragraphs[paragraphs.length - 1] += node.nodeValue;
  }
  for (var child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    walkSplittingOnBR(child);
  }
}
walkSplittingOnBR(subtree);
```

leaves `["Hello","שלום"]` in `paragraphs`.

---

> I would want "Hello" to be aligned to the left, and "שלום" to be aligned to the right.

You have three options.

1. [HTML dir attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.dir) as in `<span dir="rtl">שלום</div>` for Right-to-Left scripts like most in the Semitic language family.
2. [CSS direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/direction) as in `<span style="direction:rtl">שלום</span>`
3. [Unicode bidi embedding codepoints](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embedding) U+202A-U+202C.

Closure's [`detectRtlDirectionality`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_i18n_bidi.js.html) heuristically detects RTL text.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.getElementsByTagName("p")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName). For this to work, you would of course have to wrap the paragraphs in `<p>` tags, instead of just separating them with a `<br/>`. But `<br/>` tags are the wrong way to create paragraphs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and wrap `Text` nodes in `span` or `p` tags and give them some style (`direction`, `textAlign`, etc.):

```
var root = document.getElementById("root"),
    i,
    node,
    wrapper,
    remove = [];

for (i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++) {
    node = root.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // text node
        wrapper = document.createElement('p');
        wrapper.innerHTML = node.nodeValue.trim(); // you may want NOT to trim text node values.

        // for example:
        wrapper.style.direction = 'rtl';
        wrapper.style.textAlign = 'right';

        root.replaceChild(wrapper, node);
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        remove.push(node);
    }
}

while (remove.length > 0) {
    root.removeChild(remove.pop());
}
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/idazij/3/) Demo.